# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Django + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django, csrf

I'm running a Django v1.10.8 project. I have a form that's processed with AngularJS v1.5.6. I've put the project on a remote server that uses SSL, runs on HTTPS.

When I try submitting my custom login form, I get this error: `Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`.

`login_register.html` login form here:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<form method="post" name="loginForm" ng-submit="login()">
    <fieldset ng-disabled="submittingForm">
        <p>
            <input 
                id="{{ login_form.username.id_for_label }}"
                type="email" 
                name="{{ login_form.username.html_name }}"
                placeholder="Email"
                ng-model="login.email"
                required>
        </p>
        <p>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    id="{{ login_form.password.id_for_label }}" 
                    name="{{ login_form.password.html_name }}"
                    placeholder="{% trans 'Password (8+ characters)' %}"
                    type="[[[ login.showPW ? 'text' : 'password' ]]]" 
                    ng-minlength="{{ min_pw_length }}" 
                    ng-maxlength="{{ max_pw_length }}" 
                    ng-model="login.pw"
                    required 
                >               
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="!login.email || !login.pw">{% trans "Log in" %}</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

`login-register.js`:

```
var app=    angular.module("app",[]);
app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol("[[[");
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol("]]]");

    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName=  "csrftoken";
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName=  "X-CSRFToken";
});

app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope, $http, $window){
    $scope.loginError=  '';

    $scope.login= function(){
        $scope.submittingForm=  true;
        $scope.loginError=  '';
        var formData=   {
            "username": $scope.login.email,
            "password": $scope.login.pw
        };
        $http.post(
            "login", 
            JSON.stringify(formData)
        ).success(function(response){
            if (response.success === false){
                $scope.loginError=  response.err_msg;
                $scope.submittingForm=false;
                return;
            }
            $window.location.href=  GLOBAL_paths.home;
        });
    };
});
```

Here's an excerpt my `local_settings.py`:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "DENY"
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 60
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
```

Why do I get this 403 error despite setting the CSRF token in the JS?

Answer (score 2):

There should be a [CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/) token after the form tag

```
<form method="post" name="loginForm" ng-submit="login()">
{% csrf_token %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am gravely mistaken, and since I know little to no Angular it's very possible I am, you actually never set the actual token in your Javascript. You set up the cookie, but didn't put the token's value in it. You can access the token's raw value in your HTML with `{{ csrf_token }}`.

If I *am* incorrect, then there's also the probability that you're not using HTTPS to access the page, which would arise from you having set `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True`